# Insert line in the middle of file with standard unix tools

Tags: linux, macos, unix, sed

I can grap a specific line from a file using `sed`. Is there an easy way to take this line or paragraph and insert onto a specific line in another file?

`sed -n 1,10p >> foo` appends the result to `foo`, which places it at the bottom. Is there a standard unix tool to insert onto a specific line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for `sed`'s `r` command?

```
sed '123r file.txt' main.txt
```

inserts the contents of `file.txt` at line 123 of `main.txt`, printing everything to standard output.

(If your `sed` has the `-i` option, you can make it modify `main.txt` directly; otherwise, it will not modify its input files.)

Comment: How can I append a string, not the file.txt, to main.txt? Thanks

Comment: @Judking Post a new question instead. But briefly, you are looking for the `i` and/or `a` commands.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to replace the `n`th line in file `foo` you can do it with

```
cp foo foo.tmp
head -n $((n-1)) foo.tmp > foo
echo "newline" >> foo
tail -n +$((n+1)) foo.tmp >> foo
```

So you take the first `n-1` lines with `head -n NR`, append your new line and then append the rest starting from line `n+1` with `tail -n +NR`.

Comment: You can replace `cmd > foo; cmd >> foo; cmd >> foo` with `(cmd; cmd; cmd) > foo`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '123s|.*|sed '\''1,10!d'\'' insert.txt|e' main.txt
```